# jquery object properties value average

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object:

```
rating {
     atmosphere: 85
     cleanliness: 91
     facilities: 91
     staff: 85
     security: 94
     location: 78
     valueForMoney: 85
    }
```

How can I get the average sum of all of the properties value?

```
  $.each( json.rating, function( key, value) {
    console.log( key + ": " + value);

  });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your attempts at solving this problem.

Comment: Basic math in programming, it's the first thing you will learn if you seek out help to learn properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the object's properties to get the total value, then divide that by the number or properties in the object itself:

```
var total = 0;
for (var key in json.rating) {
    total += json.rating[key];
}
console.log(total / Object.keys(json.rating).length);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u68cm5po/)

Answer (score 2):

there is no jquery function for this. you have to do it manually

```
var count = 0;
var sum = 0;
$.each(rating, function(k, v){
   count++;
   sum += v;
});

var average = sum / count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you posted is invalid, I have modified it to a valid object, here is a working snippet

```js
var json = {
  rating: {
    atmosphere: 85,
    cleanliness: 91,
    facilities: 91,
    staff: 85,
    security: 94,
    location: 78,
    valueForMoney: 85,
  }
}
var average = 0;
var counter = 0;

$.each(json.rating, function(key, value) {
  average += value;
  counter++;
});

document.write(average / counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this:

```js
var rating  = {
     atmosphere: 85,
     cleanliness: 91,
     facilities: 91,
     staff: 85,
     security: 94,
     location: 78,
     valueForMoney: 85
    };

var totalCount = 0;
var totalSum = 0;
for(var key in rating){
  totalCount++;
  totalSum += rating[key];
}

$(".avg").text(totalSum/totalCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Average is: <div class="avg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sum the values and divide it by the length of the properties.

```js
var rating = { atmosphere: 85, cleanliness: 91, facilities: 91, staff: 85, security: 94, location: 78, valueForMoney: 85 },
    keys = Object.keys(rating),
    average = keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r + rating[k];
    }, 0) / keys.length;

document.write(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tot = 0;
$.each( json.rating, function( key, value) {
    tot += value;
});
var avg = tot / Object.keys(json.rating).length
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sum = 0, len=1;

for (var key in rating) {
  sum += rating[key];
  len++;
}

var avg = sum / len;
```