# return property from object with the highest value

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.m.hostelworld.com/1.5/properties/'+propID+'/?update-cache=true', 
          dataType: 'json', 
          headers: {
            "Accept-Language": lang 
          },
          success: function(json) { 
            var numb = 0;
            var property;
            for (var key in json.rating) {
                numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key]);
                if(json.rating[key] == numb){
                     console.log(property with the highestNumb);
                }
            }
            highestNumb = numb;
            return highestNumb;

          }, cache: false
});
```

and my object is like this:

```
rating":{
  "overall": 92,
  "atmosphere": 93,
  "cleanliness": 94,
  "facilities": 89,
  "staff": 94,
  "security": 92,
  "location": 88,
  "valueForMoney": 92
},
```

highestNumb var returns the highest value out of all of them, how can I return the property associated to the highest value, there might be a case where 2 properties will have the same highest value.

highestNumb will return 94 but I also want to access the property associated to 94 in this case cleanliness.

Comment: You can't return from a callback handler of an asynchronous call to the caller method of current method.

Comment: What should be done when two properties have the same highest value? Just return any of them?

Comment: @gurvinder372 sure you can... it just doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36595771/464709)? Right after [the other one about averaging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36595393/464709)? It looks like you're trying to crowd-source some homework.

Comment: In an Ajax callback, don't call the payload argument "json". It's no longer JSON. JSON is the data serialization used during the HTTP fetch. Once the fetch is complete, your Ajax library parses the JSON into a JavaScript value. Call the argument "data" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object is

```
var obj = {"rating":{
  "overall": 92,
  "atmosphere": 93,
  "cleanliness": 94,
  "facilities": 89,
  "staff": 94,
  "security": 92,
  "location": 88,
  "valueForMoney": 92
} // ...}
```

You can do:

```
var maxValue = -1;
var maxKey;
for (var key in obj.rating) {
   if (obj.rating[key] > maxValue) {
     maxValue = obj.rating[key];
     maxKey = key;
   }
} 

console.log(maxKey) // cleanliness
```

Note that if two properties have the same value, this will return the one that was encountered first.

Answer (score 1):

> highestNumb will return 94 but I also want to access the property
>   associated to 94 in this case cleanliness.

You need to remember the key with highest value

Make it

```
  success: function(json) { 
        var numb = 0;
        var highestProp;     
        for (var key in json.rating) {
            if ( json.rating[key] > numb )
            {
               numb = json.rating[key];
               highestProp = key;
            }                
        }
        return highestProp;
      }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var rating = {
  "overall": 92,
  "atmosphere": 93,
  "cleanliness": 94,
  "facilities": 89,
  "staff": 94,
  "security": 92,
  "location": 88,
  "valueForMoney": 92
};

var numb = 0;
var highestProp;
for (var key in rating) 
{
  if (rating[key] > numb) 
  {
    numb = rating[key];
    highestProp = key;
  }
}
alert("highest property " + highestProp );
alert("highest value " + numb );
```

Comment: highestProp always returns the last property or value

Comment: @Alex it is not returnig for me, check the demo attached